# WINDOWS OS 10 PRO

Tags: windows, cmd

При работе с командой schtasks, использовать эти ключи тогда когда если подключен удаленно ?

/U <имя пользователя>

/P [<пароль>]

/RU <пользователь> учётная запись (пользовательский контекст)

/RP [<пароль указанного пользователя>]

---

schtasks /create /s %computername% /u %UserName% /ru %UserName% /sc hourly /tn createBat /tr d:\bat\crBat.bat

Результат: Ошибка. Учетные данные пользователя не разрешены на локальном компьютере.

Успешный результат:

schtasks /create /s %computername% /sc hourly /tn createBat /tr d:\bat\crBat.bat

Почему выдает ошибку если указать локальных пользователей ? а если без них то срабатывает...

Comment: Сформулируйте вопрос более понятно.

Comment: Если комп в домене, тогда указывай пользователя в формате имя_компа\имя_пользователя. проверь лог безопасности в просмотре событий на удаленном компе, посмотри аудит отказа, почему пользователю не разрешен вход. может пользователю локальной или доменной политикой запрещен вход  через сеть.

Comment: Нет не в домене. Просто локальный компьютер домашний. У этого компьютера не настроены настройки для входа в систему через сеть.